# Looking to identify the font used for the River Road Ice House logo

Tags: font-identification

I need to identify the font in the logo below.

I read the meta post on font identification questions, and tried several of the recommended online identifiers.

What The Font gave me 5 choices, but none were correct. (For future reference, what am I supposed to enter on What The Font when it highlights multiple characters? For example, it highlighted the RIVE all in one image, but would only allow me to enter one character, so I left it blank.)

Identifont suggested ITC Mona Lisa, which is incorrect, but I can hardly blame it... I had to say "not sure" to almost everything, because I don't have a large letter sample (or any lowercase letters). The serif font identification guide gave me a lot of incorrect results, for the same reason.

So I've definitely done my due diligence... Help please? :)

[image]

Comment: Yes, just leave the box blank when it groups characters together. Or you could edit the image to add some spacing between the glyphs and try again but that's not always worthwhile

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am almost positive the font is Mesquite Std with some text effects probably done in Illustrator.

See example:

[image: font example for Mesquite Std]

Comment: There's some irony in 'stretching' a typeface based on wood type. :)

Comment: If it is not this specific one it is certainly a Somethingwood or wood-like name. And yeah, the logo suffers from the Five Blade Three Moisture Strip problem: warp, stroke, inner glow, outer glow, inner shadow, outer shadow.

Comment: Nice find, thank you! How did you figure it out? Had you seen the font before, or did you work some magic on one of the tools? :)

Comment: @WendiKidd I usually use WhatTheFont but that wouldn't easily work since the type is curved. I then checked fonts on my computer (OSX not sure if the designer before me downloaded it or if it comes with OSX) for a match. Luckily I found it that way. If that didn't work I would've either tried to straighten the font and then search that way or use keywords to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try "Mesquite", "High Country", or "High Noon".

Mesquite is an all-caps font of equal size (lowercase letters are caps equal in size to their capital counterparts).

The other two show regular lowercase letters.

There are very subtle differences in the details, but nothing too drastic.